# Creating timeuuid for cassandra inserts with apache spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am toying with apache spark and apache cassandra for data analytics and i am struggling with inserting back into cassandra with timeuuid fields.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE leech_seed_report.daily_sessions (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    app int,
    count int,
    date bigint,
    offline boolean,
    vendor text,
    version text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX daily_sessions_app_idx ON leech_seed_report.daily_sessions (app);
CREATE INDEX daily_sessions_date_idx ON leech_seed_report.daily_sessions (date);
CREATE INDEX daily_sessions_offline_idx ON leech_seed_report.daily_sessions (offline);
CREATE INDEX daily_sessions_vendor_idx ON leech_seed_report.daily_sessions (vendor);
CREATE INDEX daily_sessions_version_idx ON leech_seed_report.daily_sessions (version);
```

and i am inserting rows using

```
rows.saveToCassandra("leech_seed_report", "daily_sessions", SomeColumns("id", "date", "app", "vendor", "version", "offline", "count"))
```

and my rows consist of tuples of the format

```
([timmuuid_will_be_here], BigInt, Int, String, String, Boolean, Int)
```

i have played around with inserting into the same table without the timeuuid field and it all works fine but i cant for the life of me work out how to create a timeuuid for each row

Any help would be greatly appreciated, im new to spark, cassandra and scala and feel like im banging my head against a brick wall

Thanks
Matt.

Comment: Have your tried using [`UUIDGen`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java#L34)?

Comment: i had not, i just tried it and am getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus", im just about to try find out why, ill report back! cheers

Comment: im assuming that its a missing dependency or something, ive got it working with https://github.com/gilt/gfc-timeuuid

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I tried to use [UUIDGen](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java#L34) as suggested by [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323) but i was getting an error that i think was due to a missing dependency but im too much of a scala novice to know for sure. Having looked into a little this looks like the way I should be going but ill come back to it when I have a little more time/experiance.

I got my spark job working and generating timeuuid's using [gfc-timeuuid](https://github.com/gilt/gfc-timeuuid), it was as simple as adding the following to my build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies += "com.gilt" %% "gfc-timeuuid" % "0.0.5"
```

And then doing the following in my scala script

```
import com.gilt.timeuuid._

val tuuid = TimeUuid()
```

Answer (score 2):

Import `com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs`and call `UUIDs.timeBased()`to generate a timeuuid.

In your case:

```
rows.saveToCassandra("leech_seed_report", "daily_sessions", SomeColumns(UUIDS.timeBased(),
"date", "app", "vendor", "version", "offline", "count"))
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the below error:  `error: not found: value UUIDS`. Although I have imported the class.