# Converting UnixTimestamp to TIMEUUID for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, timeuuid

I'm learning all about Apache Cassandra 3.x.x and I'm trying to develop some stuff to play around. The problem is that I want to store data into a Cassandra table which contains these columns:

```
id (UUID - Primary Key) | Message (TEXT) | REQ_Timestamp (TIMEUUID) | Now_Timestamp (TIMEUUID)
```

REQ_Timestamp has the time when the message left the client at frontend level. Now_Timestamp, on the other hand, is the time when the message is finally stored in Cassandra. I need both timestamps because I want to measure the amount of time it takes to handle the request from its origin until the data is safely stored.

Creating the Now_Timestamp is easy, I just use the now() function and it generates the TIMEUUID automatically. The problem arises with REQ_Timestamp. How can I convert that Unix Timestamp to a TIMEUUID so Cassandra can store it? Is this even possible?

The architecture of my backend is this: I get the data in a JSON from the frontend to a web service that process it and stores it in Kafka. Then, a Spark Streaming job takes that Kafka log and puts it in Cassandra.

This is my WebService that puts the data in Kafka.

```
@Path("/")
public class MemoIn {

    @POST
    @Path("/in")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response goInKafka(InputStream incomingData){
        StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                bld.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
        }
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + bld.toString());

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(bld.toString());
        String line = obj.getString("id_memo") + "|" + obj.getString("id_writer") +
                                 "|" + obj.getString("id_diseased")
                                 + "|" + obj.getString("memo") + "|" + obj.getLong("req_timestamp");

        try {
            KafkaLogWriter.addToLog(line);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity(line).build();
    }


}
```

Here's my Kafka Writer

```
    package main.java.vcemetery.webservice;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;

public class KafkaLogWriter {

    public static void addToLog(String memo)throws Exception {
        // private static Scanner in;
            String topicName = "MemosLog";

            /*
            First, we set the properties of the Kafka Log
             */
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            props.put("acks", "all");
            props.put("retries", 0);
            props.put("batch.size", 16384);
            props.put("linger.ms", 1);
            props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
            props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

            // We create the producer
            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
            // We send the line into the producer
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, memo));
            // We close the producer
            producer.close();

    }
}
```

And finally here's what I have of my Spark Streaming job

```
public class MemoStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaSparkExample").setMaster("local[2]");
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));

        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group1");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

        /* Se crea un array con los tópicos a consultar, en este caso solamente un tópico */
        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("MemosLog");

        final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> kafkaStream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        ssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );

        kafkaStream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value()));
        // Split each bucket of kafka data into memos a splitable stream
        JavaDStream<String> stream = kafkaStream.map(record -> (record.value().toString()));
        // Then, we split each stream into lines or memos
        JavaDStream<String> memos = stream.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split("\n")).iterator());
        /*
         To split each memo into sections of ids and messages, we have to use the code \\ plus the character
          */
        JavaDStream<String> sections = memos.flatMap(y -> Arrays.asList(y.split("\\|")).iterator());
        sections.print();
        sections.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
           rdd.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords -> {
               //We establish the connection with Cassandra
               Cluster cluster = null;
               try {
                   cluster = Cluster.builder()
                           .withClusterName("VCemeteryMemos") // ClusterName
                           .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1") // Host IP
                           .build();

               } finally {
                   if (cluster != null) cluster.close();
               }
               while(partitionOfRecords.hasNext()){


               }
           });
        });

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra has no function to convert **from** UNIX timestamp. You have to do the conversion on client side.

Ref: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

Comment: I was actually referencing the same document when I asked the question. Any ideas on how to do the conversion on client side? I'm stuck here.

Comment: Depends on what client you use. Is it datastax javadriver? Perhaps you can show some of your code for what you're doing already.

Comment: The architecture of my backend is this: I get the data in a JSON from the frontend to a web service that process it and stores it in Kafka. Then, a Spark Streaming job takes that Kafka log and puts it in Cassandra. I'll edit my original post with the WebService/Kafka code and the Spark code that I've written so far.

Comment: I have no experience working with Spark but perhaps this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905698/creating-timeuuid-for-cassandra-inserts-with-apache-spark

Comment: It's not quite what I want to do but it's getting closer. Thank you so much for your help!